# bitmap not shown on button when run with dll

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

```
HBITMAP g_startcapBitmap = NULL, g_stopcapBitmap= NULL;
int nScreenWidth, ntWinx;


enum {ID_BUTTON_START=1,ID_BUTTON_STOP};  //constants for buttons
/*
 * Message loop handler for the notification window.
 */
LRESULT CALLBACK myWndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,
               WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc; 

    std::string json;
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            buttonStart = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,L"Button",L"START CAPTURE",BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,10,1,180,30,hWnd,(HMENU)ID_BUTTON_START,NULL,0);           
            g_startcapBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                        //L"StartCaptureWhite.bmp",
                                      MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
                                       IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                       180,
                                       30,
                                       LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
            if(g_startcapBitmap == NULL)
                LOG_INFO("loading startbitmap failed...!");
            if( ::SendMessage(buttonStart, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)g_startcapBitmap) == 0)
                LOG_INFO("sendimage for btnstart failed...!");


        break;


        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;



        case WM_COMMAND: //Command from Child windows and menus are under this message
             switch(wParam) //the ID is wParam
             {                  
                case ID_BUTTON_START: //check for our button ID  btnStart
                    {

                        json.clear();
                        ScreenEvent screenEvent("CONTROL","START");
                        json = screenEvent.getJSONtextAsString();
                        ScreenIndexHandler* screenIndexHandler = ScreenIndexHandler::getInstance();
                        if(screenIndexHandler == NULL )
                        {
                            LOG_INFO("Bad Screenhandler object");
                            exit(0);
                        }
                        screenIndexHandler->addToEventQueue(json);

                        ::SetWindowPos(hWnd,NULL,ntWinx,0,200,5,SWP_DRAWFRAME);

                        buttonStop = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"Button",L"STOP CAPTURE",BS_PUSHBUTTON |BS_BITMAP |  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0,0,0,0,hWnd,(HMENU)ID_BUTTON_STOP,NULL,0); 
                        g_stopcapBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                       MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2),
                                       //L"..//..//images//StopCaptureWhite.bmp",
                                       IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                       180,
                                       30,
                                       LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

                        ::SendMessage(buttonStop, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)g_stopcapBitmap);
                        ::ShowWindow(buttonStart,SW_HIDE);
                        ::UpdateWindow(hWnd);

                        NotificationWindow::isStartCap = true;
                        LOG_INFO("Added to EventQueue!");
                        break;
                    }
```

This is the code for the notification window, which gets shown when certain method of my plugin gets called.

The above code actually a part of a library(.lib) file which is used by the plugin dll.
The situation is when i link the resource file with a test program which is standalone exe, the IMAGE on the start and stop buttons get displayed.

**BUT**, when i create dll, which is part of another .sln which uses my .lib, it gets created without problem. the .dll file contains the 2 images that I am embedding using .rc file(verified using some dll-extractor tool).

Now when i invoke the **dll** through browser and call its function responsible for displaying Notification-window(with start button ), the window gets displayed BUT with **NO IMAGE** on the Start button.

Log says LoadImage() function failed and so the SendMessage().

How to solve this problem with dll.?

Is there any other way to package images for buttons/

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is probably in this piece of code:

```
LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), ...)
```

The `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` will return *always* the handle of the main EXE of the application, but your images are in the resource section of the DLL.

If you want it to run from a DLL you will have to pass any resource-loading function the `HINSTANCE` that is received by your `DllMain()` function. Alternatively you could use `GetModuleHandle("name.dll")`, but hardwiring the name of the DLL in the code is not such a good idea.

Any easy way to get the same code work in EXE and DLL is to define a global variable (do not export it!):

```
HINSTANCE g_thisModule = NULL;
```

And in the `DllMain()` function, assign to it:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    g_thisModule = hinstDll;
}
```

If instead of a DLL it is a EXE, you can get the `g_thisModule` from the argument in `WinMain()`. And if it is a console program, just add this line in `main()`: `g_thisModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);`.

Then use this variable to load any local resource:

```
LoadImage(g_thisModule, ...)
```

Comment: `HINSTANCE gInstance(NULL);
std::string g_dllPath;

// DLL Entry Point
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (!gInstance) {
        gInstance = hInstance;
        boost::scoped_array<TCHAR> strDLLPath1(new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH]);
        ::GetModuleFileName(gInstance, strDLLPath1.get(), _MAX_PATH);
        
        g_dllPath = FB::wstring_to_utf8(strDLLPath1.get());
    }
    return _AtlModule.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved);
}`
this is my ddlMain function. Please guide me how to pass HMODULE ?

Comment: Thanks a lotttttt! Actually the hardwiring approach worked for me.But I'll also try to get things done using the other approach suggested by you. Thanks again!

Comment: @rohitvk: A `HMODULE` and a `HINSTANCE` are actually the same thing in Win32, so just use in `LoadImage(gInstance,...)`. They used to be different in the good ol' days of Win16...